# Why HAML (in Ruby of Rails) cannot optionally output a <tr> and just output a <td>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

The following code is to output a 2-column table -- to output `<tr>` only every 2 items; otherwise, just a `<td>`, but I found out the output has `<tr>` all the time, for every `<td>`, why is that -- is it a bug?

```
- arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
%table
  - arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
    - if i % 2 == 0
      %tr
        %td= "column 1: #{num}"
    - else
      %td= "column 2: #{num}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you write it like this:

```
- arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
%table
  - arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
    - if i % 2 == 0
      %tr
        %td= "ODD row #{i}/#{i % 2} - column 1: #{num}"
    - else
      %td= "EVEN row #{i}/#{i % 2} - column 2: #{num}"
```

You will see the code is executed correctly. But, HAML automatically closes the `<TR>` tag (the closing comes automatically with the indentation).
And likewise, HAML automatically adds the forgotten `<TR>` tag for the dangling `<TD>`.

So one possible way to solve that:

```
- arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
%table
  - arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
    - if i % 2 == 0
      %tr
        %td= "column 1: #{num}"
        %td
          -if arr.size > i+1
            = "column 2: #{arr[i+1]}"
```

Hope this helps.

[EDIT: added erb example]

In erb you can do it a bit nicer (but i generally do not like to use it):

```
<% arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12] %>
<table>
  <%= arr.each_with_index do |num, i| %>
    <% if i % 2 == 0 %>
      <tr><td><%= "column 1: #{num}" %></td>
    <% else %>
      <td><%= "column 2: #{num}" %></td></tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: although... if doing it this way, the `arr[i+1]` is not so clean... it is like doing some "short circuit" or "hack" inside an `each` loop...

Comment: That is correct. It was just a quick suggestion that works. I edited the code to show an erb example that works, but to me it does not look much better.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use each_slice instead of each_with_index.   each_slice(2) breaks the original array into 3 groups of 2 arrays so it easier to iterate over using haml.  A touch less code too.

```
- arr = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]

%table
  - arr.each_slice(2).each do |row|
    %tr
      %td= "column 1: #{row[0]}"
      %td= "column 2: #{row[1]}"
```

Comment: you have a nice solution there, clean.  I was doing a `0.upto((arr.length / 2.0).ceil - 1) do |i| ...` which is quite gross

Comment: Very nice one, i did not know `each_slice` yet. Thanks :)